# Trying to see cellIndex value inside offsetParent for table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pull the position of a field on table and I know that the cellIndex variable contains what I am looking but I am obviously not pulling it correctly because it keeps make the 'cell' variable undefined.  Here is my what I have currently:

```
    $("span").each(function () {
        var xyzh = $(this).html();
        var cell = $(this).offsetParent.cellIndex  ;
        xyzh = xyzh.replace(/,/g, "");
        if ($.isNumeric(xyzh) && cell !== 1)
           {
            $(this).removeClass("tablesaw-cell-content");
            $(this).parent().css("text-align", "right");
           }
```

What is the correct syntax on the definition of the "cell" variable?  Or am I using this all wrong to begin with?

Thanks

Comment: `offsetParent` is a function on the jQuery object, so it needs to be invoked, and it returns a jQuery object, so you need to get the DOM element to use the `.cellIndex` property. `$(this).offsetParent()[0].cellIndex` Or use `.prop()`... `$(this).offsetParent().first().prop("cellIndex")`

Comment: @squint - just write it as an answer.

Comment: Not seem to be working.  It is confusing because when I do a debugger watch on [this] object inside offsetParent it is showing the 'nodename' as <td> but when I look at the [offsetParent returned].[0] object it is showing the node name as <div> like it is going back two spots